# Getting first Cell/Item of UICollectionView while scrolling - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have a `UICollectionView` with 1 row 1 column. I want to get the first item (`indexPath` basically) when I am scrolling it horizontally.

For example, I have got 100 items displayed horizontally in my `UICollectionView` and when I scroll from right to left, whichever item is the first one visible, I need its `indexPath`. 
Which means the `indexPath` will be constantly changing while its scrolling.

How to achieve this? Please Guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()` returns an array of `NSIndexPath` for visible cells. You can get the left most one by sorting them by `NSIndexPath.item`.

**Edti**:
To be notified while scrolling, implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll(_: UIScrollView)`. Remember that `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I know this method, but Which method would actually run while scrolling? Thats what i Need to know.

Comment: Thanks! Thats the method I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need implement `UIScrollView` delegate method and get visible cell inside

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    UICollectionViewCell *firstCell = [[collectionView visibleCells] firstObject];
    NSIndexPath *firstIndexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell: firstCell];
    NSLog(@"%@", firstIndexPath);
}
```

Hope this help